# Windows: Access directory without knowing its name

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I am writing a windows batch script, in which I would like to access `.\build\whatetherthenameis\debug`. However, I'm getting an error saying the following:

```
The system can not find the given path
```

There can only be one directory at this place and nothing else. It is a generated path, and unfortunately the name in the middle varies.

So far I've tried the following commands:

- `cd build\*\debug`
- `build\~1\debug`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the directory is only 1 level deep, it may be quicker to look for it directly instead of performing a fully recursive tree search.

```bat
@For /D %%A In (*) Do @If Exist "%%A\debug\" CD "%%A\debug"
```

Comment: It suits more to my needs than the other answer.
Thank you sir!

Comment: A nice benefit about this answer is `for /d` supports the native Unicode of the file system, unlike `for /f`. So you don't have to tinker with the console codepage to support international names.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s/b/ad ".\debug"') do cd "%%a"
```

should move you to the required directory.

perform a directory listing of `/ad` directories only `/s/b` in basic form with subdirectories, looking for `debug`. Assign each directory found to `%%a` (you claim there will be but one) and use `"delims="` to ensure the entire token is assigned.

Comment: Thank you, with a few adaptations it works perfectly

Comment: In general, if the directory name can't be represented in the current codepage (because `for /f` is a corner case in cmd.exe that was never updated to support the native UTF-16 Unicode), then you can precede this command with `chcp 65001` (UTF-8). However, a lot of programs fail with the console API's buggy implementation of UTF-8, so you may want to save and then restore the current codepage after running this command.